# OBD communication through USB

Tags: java, android, obd-ii

I am currently working on an app which intents to read data from the ECU through **OBD** and I would like to use USB adapter which I would connect to my phone. Problem is that I see bluetooth based libraries everywhere. Is there anybody willing to help me? I intend to use this library: https://github.com/pires/android-obd-reader

https://github.com/pires/obd-java-api/ (maybe this one would be better)

But I cannot figure out how to build my app, so it can communicate through usb. I have the cable and tested it with other store apps.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this, would be to use a bluetooth ELM327, and try to set up a bluetooth basic example for communication using one of the libraries.

Not sure of your knowledge, so I don't know where to start on helping you.
 1) Do you know about OBD protocols?
 2) Do you know how to request PIDS from the ECU, and read them?
 3) What vehicle are you communicating with?
 4) Are you asking for help on how to use bluetooth to communicate, or vehicle     communication with bluetooth, or both?

Bluetooth communication is essentially just serial communication, that is wireless. So first set up a basic example with the library of how to connect, and send a message. Once that is done, try sending your first message! You can try getting the RPM's (01 0C)..